# Create a awk file with some functions

Tags: awk

I have a some functions that work individually.
I´d like to join it in one awk file.
But, everytime i try to run it, return with syntax error.

dir2.awk

```
awk -F "-" '
BEGIN {
NR==1 {print $0}; 
NR==4 {print $0}};
/[0-9]/ && /N/ {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5;};
{gsub(/ N0 ./," N0.")}1;
{gsub(/ .25 /,"0.25 ")}1;
{gsub(/ .50 /,"0.50 ")}1;
{gsub(/ .75 /,"0.75 ")}1;
END {print "FIM";}'
```

file
CODE

```
000224123


                    -       316.0    -      316.00    -         .00   -  N0 .00E  -
                    -       323.0    -      323.00    -         .00   -  N0 .00E  -
                    -       350.0    -      350.00    -         .25   -  N44.00W  -
                    -       380.0    -      380.00    -         .25   -  N74.00E  -
                    -       410.0    -      410.00    -         .25   -  N15.00E  -
                    -       440.0    -      440.00    -         .25   -  N34.00E  -
                    -       470.0    -      470.00    -         .25   -  N54.00E  -
                    -       500.0    -      500.00    -         .25   -  N16.00E  -
                    -       530.0    -      530.00    -         .25   -  N07.00E  -
                    -       560.0    -      560.00    -         .25   -  N03.00W  -
                    -       590.0    -      590.00    -         .25   -  N09.00W  -
                    -       620.0    -      620.00    -         .50   -  N18.00W  -
                    -       650.0    -      649.99    -         .50   -  N19.00W  -
                    -       680.0    -      679.99    -         .50   -  N26.00W  -
                    -       710.0    -      709.99    -         .50   -  N13.00W  -
                    -       740.0    -      739.99    -         .75   -  N15.00W  -
                    -       770.0    -      769.99    -         .50   -  N02.00W  -
                    -       800.0    -      799.99    -         .75   -  N01.00W  -
```

Comment: It's not clear what you expect your script to do - the syntax error seems to be because you have rules (`NR==1` and `NR==4`) **inside** the `BEGIN` rule

Comment: Even after fixing the BEGIN problem, that code is going to produce a lot of duplicate (or near-duplicate) output lines.   one for each of the gsub lines.

Answer (score 2):

The following probably doesn't do exactly what you want, but it will at least run and should be a reasonable base to get your desired output:

(it's hard to tell what you want because it's unclear whether the sample data you provided is the input or the output...I've assumed that it's input)

```
awk -F "-" '
  NR==1 || NR==4 {print $0; next};

  /[0-9]/ && /N/ {
    gsub(/ N0 \./," N0.");

    gsub(/^ *\./,"0.",$4);

    print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5;
  }

  END {print "FIM";}'
```

The important changes are:

- got rid of the BEGIN block.  Lines 1 and 4 are just printed verbatim.  Note the `next` statement - that prevents any further processing of those lines.
- grouped all the `gsub()`s and the `print` into a block that is only executed on matching lines
- the `gsub()` transformations happen BEFORE the print statement.
- folded the three `gsub()` operations to fix the decimal number in field 4 to just one that prepends a `0` if $4 begins with zero-or-more spaces and a `.`.